# Какие аргументы добавить в Visual Studio для правильного запуска просмотра с помощью Opera?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, opera

При запуске проекта asp.net открывается Opera 42.

При повторном запуске не открывается, не может открыть копию браузера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно открыть проект в новой вкладке а не копии браузера.

Какие аргументы добавить в Visual Studio для правильного запуска просмотра с помощью Opera?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В других браузерах ошибки нету.